# How to chain a list of RxJS observable

Tags: angular, rxjs6

Using Angular CLI 6 for a Single Page Application

What I need to do is the following
make an HTTP post request. I will get an OK back. The results or the side effect will take sometime before is ready for processing.
I will have to poll for results readiness, lets say once a second.

To poll for the results, I need to make an HTTP get call and check the results. If results are complete, I am done.
Otherwise I will have to continue to poll..

What I have done, I have two obserables, one for the HTTP post and one for HTTP get call. 
I use a setTimeout for the polling. This organization for the code, when I hit the setTimeout, I go to never never land I have to kill the application...

Any hints on this problem?

What I have so far is

```
private initiateAnalysis(){
    this.initiateRequest$()
    .subscribe(response =>{
            const error = getErrorMessage(response);
            if (error !== null) {
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                this.processResults();
            }
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) =>{
            console.error('feature error:', err);
        });
}

private initiateRequest$(): Observable<any>{
    let params: any = {
    };
    return this.problemsService.postRequest('postURL', {}, params)
}

private checkForResponse$(): Observable<any>{
    let params: any = {
    };

    return this.problemsService.getResults('someURL', params);
}

private processResults(){
    this.doneWithNecRiskAnalysis = false;
    while (!this.doneWithNecRiskAnalysis) {
        setTimeout(() =>{
            this.checkForResults();   // I never to this line in the code...
        }, 1000);
    }
}

private checkForResults() {
    this.checkForResponse$()
    .subscribe(response =>{
            const error = getErrorMessage(response);
            if (error !== null) {
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                if (1 === 1) { // just for now
                    this.showResults(response.payload);
                }
            }
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) =>{
            console.error('feature error:', err);
        });
}

private showResults(results) {
    console.log('results', results);
}
```

Comment: If you want us to explain the problem with your code, you need to post your code.

Comment: I think the observable which do the polling should use setInterval and Call onNext after the http-request. Then you can use the takeWhile operator

Comment: thank you, I read about the usage of takeWhile, looks very promising. Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say: "setInterval and Call onNext"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (!this.doneWithNecRiskAnalysis) {
    setTimeout(() =>{
        this.checkForResults();   // I never to this line in the code...
    }, 1000);
}
```

This constantly asks the server to check for results in 1 seconds. You never wait for the next second before asking again.

The first thing I would do to make your code much, much simpler and cleaner is to refactor your services (and/or your backend) so that their observable emits an **error** if there is an error, rather than emitting a normal even with an error message.

The remaining will assume you have done that.

You should also stop using the `any` type.

Then the code can be simplified to the following:

```
  private initiateAnalysis() {
    this.initiateRequest$().pipe( // sends the first request to start the analysis
      switchMap(() => interval(1000)), // when the response comes back, start emitting an event every second from this observable
      mergeMap(() => this.checkForResponse$()), // each second, send the GET request and emit the results. Merge all the results into the resulting observable
      filter(results => this.isAnalysisComplete(results)), // filter out the results if they are not the final, correct results
      first() // only take the first complete results, to avoid continuing sending GET requests
    ).subscribe(results => this.showResults(results));
  }

  private initiateRequest$(): Observable<void> {
    const params = {
    };
    return this.problemsService.postRequest('postURL', {}, params)
  }

  private checkForResponse$(): Observable<Results>{
    const params = {
    };

    return this.problemsService.getResults('someURL', params);
  }

  private showResults(results: Results) {
    console.log('results', results);
  }
```

You might prefer using `concatMap()` instead of `mergeMap()` if you want to wait for the previous response before sending the next request.

Here's a demo wher ethe actual HTTP request are replaced by random delays and random responses: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bt17fb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: so this is great, thank you so much. Except there is one problem. You are assuming that the first response from the get and the processing ends. This is incorrect. I need to poll for the get to send a "suitable" response, i.e get a response, check it for existence of some value and only then showResults. With  your example I only process the get result once and I end the procession and show results. Makes sense?

Comment: No. Not at all. You didn't read the code and the comments, and you didn't try the demo. Do it. `filter(results => this.isAnalysisComplete(results)), // filter out the results if they are not the final, correct results`

Comment: My apologies, just now I noticed it. Thank you so very much.